# Deployment of PHP app on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I zipped all my files before uploading it to elastic beanstalk. However I'm getting an error message:
Not Found
The requested URL /was not found on this server.

I did some research and came across the following post:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=127927

"The '403 Forbidden' error was because of the file structure of the zip folder. In order to upload properly please highlight/select all the contents "inside" the folder then you can compress/zip the contents and not the folder itself. That is, you cannot have a nested folder inside the zip."

I have done as told, except that I have selected the files AND 2 folders which contain some files. This may be causing the issue(?)

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that you are facing “**The requested URL /was not found on this server**”, you need to ensure the following:

> 1: Make sure your application has the file that **.htaccess** is
>   redirecting to your welcome page.  
> 2: You need to set the public
>   folder as the root folder. For this, go to the Elastic Beanstalk
>   Console and Click on “Configurations”, then modify Software . Update
>   the “**Document root**” to the folder that contains your site's
>   default page. For example /public if the welcome page is in a folder
>   named public.